# How are really big maps made?

Tags: tilemap, maps, level-design, levels

I'm interested in how *huge* games like The Witcher 3 and Skyrim create and save the open worlds. In my own game I used a system where I stored the map data in a file seperated by commas. For example 'stone' would code for a stone tile, and I just typed in codes for how I wanted my map to appear in the game.

I feel like this was a really innefficient and incorrect way of doing things. But, I couldn't think of a different way to get past the problem.

The creators of skyrim obviously used a level editor, but how did they actually save a map as big as skyrim's world? How is the data stored? Because with something as intricate as an amazing, 3D world, you can't store it like I did by just having codewords for different tiles that are all the same height and width.

How is it done in 2D games as well? For example Ori and the Blind Forest, which does not use a tile-based system. Or, in fact, do they not have files that hold data for the level layouts at all?

Thanks :)

Comment: In general, we can't tell you "How did Game X implement Feature Y." Those details are often known only to the developers who actually worked on that implementation, and they may be barred from discussing them by non-disclosure agreements. Can you try editing your question to ask "How can I implement Feature Y in my game" instead? This has two big advantages: 1) it doesn't require insider knowledge to be able to answer, helping you get answers faster, and 2) maybe Game X's way of doing this isn't even right for your game. By asking about your own game, you get answers suited to your own needs.

Comment: There's also [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/138853/how-can-large-terrains-be-represented-in-multiplayer-games) that might be useful, as might perusing the results of a [search for "map chunk"](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=map+chunk) in general, since that's the basic strategy.

Comment: One hint is: not as plain text. Do some research on binary formats; they're typically faster to load and provide more efficient storage, as a tradeoff against being more complex (but that's where tools such as map editors and compilers come in).